# How to merge several data frames with same row names(and col names) without changing the order?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
##Make up 3 data frames 

Var<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11")
res <- c(2,3.1,4.5,5.1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,11.8,12.3) 
df_1 <- data.frame(res,Var)

Var<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11")
res <- c(2.2,3.3,4.5,5.1,6.5,13,0,0,10.1,1,12.3) 
df_2 <- data.frame(res,Var)

Var<- c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11")
res <- c(0,3.3,0,5.1,6.5,13,0,1,10.1,1,1) 
df_3 <- data.frame(res,Var)

merged_df<- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(df_1,df_2,df_3))
```

The problem here is that I want the "merged_df" to have rows "t1" of df_1 then "t1" of df_2 and then "t1"of df_3 and so on but the above function sort them based on value!

Any idea how to overcome this?
Thanks

Comment: do you have a way to sort the rows after merging?

Comment: That's a part of my question

Comment: what if you reverse the order of the by variables, `by = c('Var', 'res')` ? or `merged_df[order(factor(merged_df$Var, unique(df_1$Var))), ]` if you want to sort after merging -- this would require `sort = FALSE` in your `merge` statement

Comment: @rawr If I do the following:`merged_df<- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE,sort=FALSE), list(df_1,df_2,df_3))`

`merged_df<- merged_df[order(factor(merged_df$Var, unique(df_1$Var))), ]`                                                                                    it still mess it up and also removes redundant rows

Comment: @Jack I get the same number of rows that you have in `merged_df` in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# assign grp variables
df_1$grp <- 'df_1'  
df_2$grp <- 'df_2'
df_3$grp <- 'df_3'

# merge data frames
long_df <- do.call('rbind', list(df_1, df_2, df_3))

# output
head( long_df )
#   res Var  grp
# 1 2.0  t1 df_1
# 2 3.1  t2 df_1
# 3 4.5  t3 df_1
# 4 5.1  t4 df_1
# 5 6.5  t5 df_1
# 6 7.1  t6 df_1
```

Sort the column `Var`

```
long_df <- within( long_df, Var <- factor( Var, 
                                           levels = c("t1","t2","t3","t4","t5","t6","t7","t8","t9","t10","t11"),
                                           ordered = TRUE ))

sort_long_df <- with( long_df, long_df[ order(Var), ])
head(sort_long_df, 10)
#    res Var  grp
# 1  2.0  t1 df_1
# 12 2.2  t1 df_2
# 23 0.0  t1 df_3
# 2  3.1  t2 df_1
# 13 3.3  t2 df_2
# 24 3.3  t2 df_3
# 3  4.5  t3 df_1
# 14 4.5  t3 df_2
# 25 0.0  t3 df_3
# 4  5.1  t4 df_1
```